# About the proof of the Hahn decomposition theorem on Wikipedia

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading through the proof of the [Hahn decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) on Wikipedia. There was the following part which I could not make sense of:

> Since the sets $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are disjoint subsets of $D$, it follows from the sigma additivity of the signed measure $\mu$ that
>   $$\mu(A)=\mu(D)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu(B_n)\le\mu(D)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\min\{1,t_n/2\}.$$

The definition of signed measure used by the article is that, a signed measure is a maping $$\mu:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow (-\infty,\infty],$$ satisfying the sigma additivity property. So $\mu$ is not allowed to take the value $-\infty$.

But now my question is:

> Given sets $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ with $A \subset B$. Then one has due to the sigma additivity of the signed measure $\mu$ that $\mu(A)=\mu((A\setminus B) ⊍ B)=\mu(A \setminus B) + \mu(B)$. But to now subtract $\mu(B)$ one has to make sure that $\mu(B) < \infty$. And I do not see in the proof how $\mu(\bigcup B_n)= \sum_n\mu(B_n)<\infty$? So how can it be that $$\mu(A)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu(B_n)=\mu(D) \implies \mu(A)=\mu(D)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu(B_n),$$
>   for $D=A \setminus \bigcup_n B_n$ for disjoint $B_n$ disjoint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$|\mu(D)|< \infty$.
In any signed measure space, if a set $D$ has a finite measure, then any subset $B$ has finite measure.
This is true because a signed measure can't assume both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, hence if $\mu(B)=+\infty$, finite additivity of $\mu$ with its complement $D-B$ must fail.